# Change Custom status(Ready to ship) using rest api in magento2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status, rest-api

I will create one custom order-status (Ready to Ship) in Magento-2.1.12.How to change this status using rest API in magento.2.1.12?Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: tell me anyone.

Comment: See my answer to your question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232648/how-to-change-order-status-with-custom-order-statusready-to-dispatch-using-res/281276#281276)