# How to change Order-Status with custom-order-status(Ready To Dispatch) using rest API in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, order-status, rest-api

I have one custom order status(Ready To Dispatch).I want to change order-status of order using rest api.Please help me i don't know what api is used?

Comment: Please guide me its very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Use [a comment to set the status](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/salesOrderManagementV1/salesOrderManagementV1AddCommentPost)
by HTTP POST-ing the payload (see link) with desired **status code** to this endpoint

```
http(s)://{host}/index.php/rest/V1/orders/{orderId}/comments
```

you can update the status of an order